# Image uploading error while hosting

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am new in web development and came across this error when trying to upload image to my server using php. Does anybody has the solution to this problem? Your help is very much appreciated.

> **Security Alert**
>
> The file you are uploading was rejected by the server. It probably
>   contents viruses or trojans that can damage your website Do not
>   attempt to upload it again as your IP address may be blocked.

Comment: Contact the customer support of your hosting provider!

Comment: The problem is not realated to php it is related with your hosting provider. Contact you hosting provider and ask him for the solution

Comment: And perform a virus scan on your computer :-)